# Using personalisation strings in landing pages

Tags: javascript, marketing-cloud, ampscript, visualforce

I was just wondering is there anyway to populate personlisation strings in landing pages?

I know that I can set variables and access these via @[variable_name], however I have a landing page, that reuses a block from an email that displays different content based on a personalisation string.

Is there anyway to populate these in a lnding page so I don't get an error? Alternatively does anyone have some code I could add to the block to allow me to switch between personalisation strings and variables?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can populate them if you use the [**MicrositeURL()**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en-US/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/micrositeurl/) function in your email to reference your landing page.  That will encode and pass all of personalization strings in the URL.  Once on the page, you can reference them like you would in an email -- `%%varname%%` for personalization strings, `%%=v(@varname2)=%%` for variables you create in the page.  In order for the links to wrap in your test email, you have to actually send it, not just use Send Preview.

Comment: Hi Adam, Thanks for this, however this wouldn't help in this situation. As the question says I have a landing page that reuses a content block from the email - this means it has personlaisation strings (%%nameHere%%) present within it. These are what I need to populate, prefereably without changing them to variables as I also need to use the block at send time. Hope this makes sense, but thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: You can use the `%%_messagecontext%%` personalization string to detect if you are in a landing page or email.  If it's a landing page you can retrieve the subscriber data via AMPScript or SSJS API call.  I've seen this used in to display alternate content on the view-as-a-webpage version of the email. In that scenario, the personalization data is retrieved from the [SendLog](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/send_logging/).

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for that - that does look interesting. With the system we're building we use a centralised content model so our client can change one block and it affects multiple emails - so the landing page actually allows the client to change the blocks within an email and preview that change before making the change live. This means that the email won't have been sent yet. We do send from data extensions so I'll have another look at the functions round this and see if I can come up with something.